# Conditionally set 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY' if ID is not provided on insert

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have a the following DDL and would like to generate an ID on insert to the table, but ONLY if the ID has not been provided already.

```sql
drop table if exists table1;
create table table1 (
    pk_id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    other_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY -- DO THIS ONLY IF NULL
)
```

I was thinking of using a stored procedure to do this and have attempted a start with the below code, but have been unable to get it working:

```sql
create or replace function conditionally_generated_identity(other_id integer)
    returns table (id integer) as $$
begin
    if other_id is null then
        return query other_id generated always as identity;
    elsif other_id is not null then
        return query other_id;
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Not possible and a bad idea: When I use id number 25, what number should the generator use for the next record without an id when the last one was number 24?

Comment: That makes no sense at all to me. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: The `other_id` may exist in another table. The server intercepts a `table1` record, and checks to see if `other_id` exists, if it does, it just sets it, if not I want it to generate it. 

I know this is a little dodgy, but I am unsure how else to solve this issue.

Comment: If `other_id` is a foreign key, then that value should be generated in the _other_ table.

Comment: OK. So then what about the case where the key hasn't been generated by the _other_ table?

Comment: Isn't `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope. I am looking for a conditionally set identity, but the crowd is right. This is suspect.

Comment: The child value in the referencing field(`table1.other_id`)  in a FK relationship can be `NULL`. Still one would expect that the child records would be created after the parent and would have access to the parent value when the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` was constructed.